# How to remove strings with numbers and special characters using regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

Remove strings with numbers and special characters using regular expression.Here is my code

```
  var string = "[Account0].&[1]+[Account1].&[2]+[Account2].&[3]+[Account3].&[4]";
    var numbers = string.match(/(\d+)/gi);
    alert(numbers.join(','));
```

here output is : 0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4

But i want the following output  1,2,3,4

Can any one please help me.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seemd what you want is [\d+], use exec like this,

```
var myRe = /\[(\d+)\]/gi;

var myArray, numbers = [];

while ((myArray = myRe.exec(string)) !== null) {
    numbers.push(myArray[1]);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xE265/

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
string = "[Account0].&[1]+[Account1].&[2]+[Account2].&[3]+[Account3].&[4]";
repl = string.replace(/.*?\[(\d+)\][^\[]*/g, function($0, $1) { return $1 });
//=> "1234"
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the simplest solution in this case would be:

```
\[(\d+)\]
```

simply saying that you only want the digits enclosed by brackets.

Regards